# Why Heroku can't find my Django templates?

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment

I deployed my project on Heroku. But it can't find my templates(Source doesn't exist):

[image]

My project architecture:

[image]

**settings.py:**

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**UPDATE**: All templates from the Account app load with this extending

Comment: Note that Django is looking for authors, but you have a folder named author

Comment: Do you have a template `base/base.html` and where is it located?

Comment: templates/base/base.html

Comment: @LiorPollak, it's alright, because for the app "author" I have the URL path "/authors"

Comment: Well then the error is pretty descriptive. You need to have a base html template.

Comment: I have it. It's located in templates/base/base.html. It exists, because locally everything works well

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. There was extra whitespace, like `{% extends 'base/base.html ' %}`